# Guice class properties are always null; Factory is never called/used

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

---

Trying to inject objects into classes but can't seem to get my factory to be called, let alone the object into the class I want it in.

The factory class should return a instance of AmazonSQS.

```
public class AmazonFactory implements Provider<AmazonSQS> {

    @Override
    public AmazonSQS get() {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("KEY", "SECRET");

        return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
            .build();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the parameter the Provider takes is what should be returned in the `get()` method. I think I've done this correctly so far.

I then have a module

```
public class AmazonModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(AmazonSQS.class).toProvider(AmazonFactory.class);
    }
}
```

My thought here is that whenever I request AmazonSQS I should actually be getting the result of the factory (the result of the `get()` method?)

And then I'm just adding the module to my app in the init function (Dropwizard app using guicy so a little different but shouldn't matter)

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<SwordfishConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.builder()
        .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
        .useWebInstallers()
        .modules(new BaseModule())
        .build());

}
```

*Dropwizard specifics, works the same if I just add AmazonModule to the init method*

```
public class BaseModule extends DropwizardAwareModule<Configuration> {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new AmazonModule());

        configuration();
        environment();
        bootstrap();
    }
}
```

I can confirm `AmazonModule` is being called during app startup so the init part is right so far.

However if I try and use the `AmazonSQS` object it's always null.

Example:

```
public class QueueUtils {

    @Inject
    private AmazonSQS amazonSQS;

    public QueueUtils() {

    }

    public void sendMessage(String queueUrl, String payload) {
        amazonSQS.sendMessage(payload);
    }

}
```

The `amazonSQS.sendMessage(payload);` will fail as `amazonSQS` is null.

I've just started trying to figure Guice out so if I've missed some core concept or my thinking is completely wrong, would love some pointers to get me in the right direction.

The documentation is a bit overwhelming or very hard to transfer the examples into my application.

Cheers

Comment: your initialization code has `.modules(new BaseModule())`. where did you tell Guice about `AmazonModule`?

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya Sorry was a bad copy/paste - have updated however.

Comment: how is `QueueUtils` created? Guice show somehow *know* about it, otherwise it won't do any bindings for it

Comment: you can simply try by adding `bind(QueueUtils.class` in `AmazonModule`.

Comment: At the moment it's just been called `QueueUtils queueUtils = new QueueUtils();`. I added `bind(QueueUtils.class);` but that had no effect.

Comment: `QueueUtils queueUtils = new QueueUtils();` won't work, because as i said before, Guice doesn't *know* about the instance you created. you need to create it using Guice.

Comment: Yup got that now, but isn't that what `bind(QueueUtils.class)`? I've just tried to create a provider for `queueUtils` which is now also just returning null;

Comment: Okay I've solved it. The real problem was I was trying to use the @Inject in a sundial (quartz) task which had no idea about Guice. @ketanvijayvargiya it was your helpful comment about Guice not knowing about `QueueUtils` that sent me down that path to work that out, so thank you very much :)

Comment: You should add that as an answer. It may help someone else and people don't always read the (extended) comments